# How to get size of widget from custom widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have the following custom widget:

```
MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  Widget child;
......
  const MyWidget(
      {Key key,
      this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //get child's size and use it in layout
  }
}
```

How can I reach this? I know that I can do it using global keys but as I see this solution doesn't work here.

How would I do it if I didn't need to create separate StatelessWidget: I'd create GlobalKey and provided it in constructor, but here I can't provide it in constructor because I have already created child Widget in my custom widget.

Comment: Can you post the full code? It's hard to understand, what child you want to get the size from. Or you want to know how much space can your "MyWidget" take in it's parent?

Comment: No, not MyWidget. I need to get size of property called child which I pass to the constructor inside the build method.

Comment: `Size of the child widget` in respect of `height` or something else @IlyaMaximencko ?

Comment: In my case I need height of child widget

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `GlobalKey` for a widget wrapping the `child` widget, e.g., a `Container` or an `IntrinsicHeight`(which sets its height to its child's height) and get this widget's size using that key:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  MyWidget({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  final GlobalKey key1 = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        IntrinsicHeight(child: child, key: key1),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(key1.currentContext.size);
          },
          child: Text('get height'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```